# What does the command php bin/composer.phar do?

Tags: php, composer-php, phar

To install [Composer](https://getcomposer.org/) in my shared host, I ran from my home directory:

`$ curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php -- --install-dir=bin`

Then I was told to run: `$ php bin/composer.phar`

And following that I was able to use Composer, confirmed by running:

```
$ composer.phar -V 
Composer version 1.0-dev
```

Can someone please explain the command `php bin/composer.phar`?

Is it simply telling php to unpack the .phar file? If so, where does it unpack it to? I see `bin/bin/composer.phar*` after having run it. Then I have to run composer using the entire path to the phar file, unless I'm in the home directory.

Comment: Phars are just unpacked in-memory: http://php.net/manual/en/intro.phar.php, also when run as CLI invocation script.

Comment: if you have composer.json, then when called composer.phar, composer install necessary frameforworks/modules/applications and etc, which lists in your composer.json file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `.phar` file is a ZIP-like file that contains all the files that make up a PHP application, and some initial code in the file header that sets up some stuff and then transfers execution to the first zipped file.

The command `php bin/composer.phar` is calling PHP and gives the phar file as a parameter to make PHP execute that file. This will make PHP read that file, find the header with the bootstrapping code and execute that. PHP will initialize PHAR execution and go further into that compressed file.

The command `composer.phar` will only work if that file has been marked with the x file flag to make it executable, and it is placed in a directory that is mentioned in the `$PATH` environment variable. Part of the PHAR file is the first line of the file header that is called "shebang". This line is used in all script files for the command line to specify the interpreter that should be used to execute the file. In case of `composer.phar`, this interpreter is PHP. So in essence, the same thing happens as with the first call: PHP is "running" the PHAR file, but with less typing on the command line.

Comment: (Not all Phar archives are actual ZIP files though. There are three varieties, the custom binary Phar format being the most common. - Composer itself splendidly fails at extracting ZIP-Phars.)

Comment: I corrected the reference to ZIP as a file format. PHP supports a native Phar format as well as TAR and ZIP, with the former being preferred over the two latter.

Comment: I like the description from the link @mario shared that "Phar is kind of like a thumb drive for PHP applications." So it's kind of like a zipped file who's content is available as a stream and can actually function as an application directly within the memory php is using, right?